# Calculate an algorithm for hit chance in an RPG

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate an algorithm and implement it in C# that will calculate the hit chance against an enemy in a role playing game.

Essentially, if my character's dexterity is equal to my opponent's, my hit chance is 90%. If my dexterity is 500% of my opponent's, my hit chance is 100%, and if my opponent's is 500% of mine, then my hit chance is 0%.

I've been looking up curve fitting formulas for an hour and my brain is wracked.

Maybe this is too complicated of a way to determine hit chance? Maybe someone has a better solution to offer as well?

Comment: This question is maybe better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com, because I think you are asking for an algorithm, rather than a specific implementation of it in C#...

Comment: @Spontifixus or math.stackexchange?

Comment: So, you mentioned (the most extreme) three points now. How should it behave when it’s somewhere inbetween? That decision ultimately decides how your graph/function will look like.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry -- I actually didn't even know there was that website. I've only ever come here for programming questions, and I already knew this was more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Linear interpolation, Lagrange interpolation; if you are going to have many intermediate points, not only 100% dexterity - 90% hit 500% - 100%, 20% - 0% see spline interpolation

Comment: @Kippie the question is, whether OP is interested in a programmable algorithm, or the mathematical background of such...

Comment: @poke, I thought my description would give a good idea of how the curve behaves, but maybe not. Let me throw a few estimated numbers. 250% of my opponent's dex would give your hit somewhere in the ballpark of 95% hit chance, whereas my opponent's being 250% of mine would bring my hit chance down to around 50%. Those numbers aren't exact, whereas the original numbers I gave were. For example, if my opponent's Dex is 4, I would need my Dex to be 20 to become unhittable by my opponent.

Comment: i'd use `hitchance = 0.9^(dexEnemy/dexOwn)`: equal -> 0.9^1. if you want your 500% condition, multiply values accordingly. Advantage: This NEVER gets you 100% or 0%, just pretty close to. :)

Comment: @dognose - I think I like that even better than my 500% values. I'm toying with numbers right now and I like what I see.

Comment: @JonathanPlumb Well, imagine it like this: You have a coordinate system; on the x-axis is your dexterity, on the y-axis the hit chance. So you originally mentioned three points: `(0,90)`, `(-500,0)` and `(500,100)`. If you draw those points in the coordinate system, you still have infinite possibilities on how to connect those points with a curve. Even with more individual points, it’s still the same. So you should think about how that curve should look like in total.

Comment: You're looking for the D20 rule.. look it up, it's used in pretty much all iterations of this sort of gameplay. In fact, here it is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D20_System

Comment: @Simon Whitehead - I'm trying to steer away from the D20 system. I want my game to be unique and not have everyone and their dog know exactly what stats they need for a perfect character, etc. I like the "unknown"

Answer (score 3):

I didnt test this, but it seems to be what you want:

```
double higherd = Math.Max(mydexterity, oppdexterity);
double lowerd  = Math.Min(mydexterity, oppdexterity);

//(500%-100%)/100% * 25% = 400%/100% * 25% = 4* 25% = 100%
double d_hitchance = (higherd - lowerd) / (lowerd) * 0.25D;

double higher_hitchance = d_hitchance * 0.1D + 0.9D;

double lower_hitchance = 0.9D - d_hitchance * 0.9D;

double myhitchance = (mydexterity==higherd)? higher_hitchance : lower_hitchance;
double opphitchance = (oppdexterity==higherd)? higher_hitchance : lower_hitchance;
```

you might have to clamp the chances between 0 and 1.0, when more than 500% difference

Comment: Thanks - I'm going with dognose's formula, but I'm going to write this down as well in-case I want to come back to this 500% idea.